# why THEME_preprocess_menu_block_wrapper is never called

Tags: 7, theming

```
function mytheme_preprocess_menu_block_wrapper(&$variables, $hook) {
  $zebra = 0;
  foreach (element_children($variables['content']) as $mlid){
    $variables['content'][$mlid]['#attributes']['class'][] = ($zebra % 2) ? 'even' : 'odd';
    $zebra++;
  }
}
```

Taken from http://drupal.org/node/1503938

I can flush every cache in drupal 7 and it won't work, putting die statements in the code of the function proves this so what's the deal, other template theme functions I've added work just fine.

Comment: are you using the Menu Block Module (http://drupal.org/project/menu_block) for your menu?

Comment: No, just the only menu modules I have are Menu Trail By Path, Menu, Administration menu and Administration menu Toolbar style

Comment: Per the last comment on the page this is taken from, "Don't think it's made clear here, but to do this you need to be using the menu_block module for your menus."

Comment: Did you change "mytheme" in the function call to the theme that you're using? And then flushing the cache?

Comment: Jimajamma if you post the comment as an answer I'll award you it.  chrisjlee the questions answered and yes I did those things :)